# Testing a Concept type in Hypledger Composer with Cucumber

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

If you had an Address concept (as demonstrated [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/cto_language.html)), then how would you write the cucumber features to account for a required Address concept on an asset?  I see how to do it with the mocha.js examples using factory.newConcept() but is it possible to pull this off using cucumber?

```
  And I have added the following assets of type org.acme.Address
      | addressId   | street1         | city    | state    | zipcode  |
      | AddressA    | 123 West 3rd   | Anywhere  | Texas    | 12345    |
      | AddressB    | 123 West 3rd | Anywhere  | Texas    | 12345   |
  And I have added the following assets of type org.acme.Delivery
      | loadId   | start    | end |
      | 1        |  AddressA  | AddressB    |
      | 2        | AddressA  | AddressB    |
```

Models defintion:

```
concept Address {
  o String street1
  o String street2 optional
  o String city
  o String state
  o String zipcode
  o Double latitude optional
  o Double longitude optional
}

asset Delivery identified by loadId {
  o String loadId
  o Address start
  o Address end
}
```

I have tried passing a hash of arguments in the start column but that didn't work and received the error

> ValidationException: Model violation in instance org.acme.Delivery#1
>   class org.acme.Address has value addressConcept expected a Resource or
>   a Concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing complex data using Cucumber, you need to use JSON instead of the data table format. There's an example here:

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-cucumber-steps/features/assets.feature#L14

```
Scenario: given I have added the following asset
    Given I have added the following asset
        """
        {"$class":"org.acme.sample.SampleAsset", "assetId":"1", "owner":"alice@email.com", "value":"10"}
        """
    Then I should have the following asset
        """
        {"$class":"org.acme.sample.SampleAsset", "assetId":"1", "owner":"alice@email.com", "value":"10"}
        """
```

Wherever you see a data table, you should be able to provide JSON instead - including arrays:

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-cucumber-steps/features/assets.feature#L34

```
Scenario: given I have added the following assets
    Given I have added the following assets
        """
        [
            {"$class":"org.acme.sample.SampleAsset", "assetId":"1", "owner":"alice@email.com", "value":"10"},
            {"$class":"org.acme.sample.SampleAsset", "assetId":"2", "owner":"bob@email.com", "value":"20"}
        ]
        """
    Then I should have the following assets
        """
        [
            {"$class":"org.acme.sample.SampleAsset", "assetId":"1", "owner":"alice@email.com", "value":"10"},
            {"$class":"org.acme.sample.SampleAsset", "assetId":"2", "owner":"bob@email.com", "value":"20"}
        ]
        """
```

Comment: Thank you Simon.  You are very helpful and a wealth of knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Simon’s answer is good, but does not actually answer the question that was asked (though it does in a sort of round about way).

If I may, I’d like to take a stab (I'm assuming `org.acme` is the namespace):

The Gherkin you need looks like this:

```
Scenario: given I have added the following asset
    Given I have added the following asset
    """
    {"$class":"org.acme.Delivery", "loadId":"1", "start":{"$class":"org.acme.Address", "addressId":"AddressA", "street1":"123 West 3rd", "city":"Anywhere", "state": "Texas", "zipcode":"12345"}, "end":{"$class":"org.acme.Address", "addressId":"AddressB", "street1":"123 West 3rd", "city":"Anywhere", "state": "Texas", "zipcode":"12345"}}
    """
    Then I have added the following asset
    """
    {"$class":"org.acme.Delivery", "loadId":"1", "start":{"$class":"org.acme.Address", "addressId":"AddressA", "street1":"123 West 3rd", "city":"Anywhere", "state": "Texas", "zipcode":"12345"}, "end":{"$class":"org.acme.Address", "addressId":"AddressB", "street1":"123 West 3rd", "city":"Anywhere", "state": "Texas", "zipcode":"12345"}}
    """
```

Notice the *nested* Address object using standard JSON nesting syntax.

Again, I think Simon's answer was fine, but if you’re not a JSON expert, extending his answer (to a completely different scenario) to the one that was asked might be challenging.

Aside from the fact that the start and end addresses are identical (and 12345 is not a valid zip code in Texas), this should answer the exact question that was asked.

--jsp